# Gradle task hierarchy

Tags: gradle

I tried to write my own Gradle Tasks:

```
task(incVersion) << {
[...]
}

task cleanDocBuild(dependsOn: ['clean','cleanDoc','incVersion','asciidoctor','war']) << {

    cleanDoc.dependsOn clean
    incVersion.dependsOn cleanDoc
    asciidoctor.dependsOn incVersion
    war.dependsOn asciidoctor

    println 'Start Building...'
}

task(cleanDoc) << {   
[...]
}

asciidoctor {
[...]
}
```

I want to call the tasks in a specific order:

- clean
- clenDoc
- incVersion
- asciidoctor
- war

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set not only `dependsOn` property of the task (this property doesn't make any ordering, just provide task dependencies), but also `mustRunAfter` or `shouldRunAfter`, according to your needs, to make this tasks run in predefined order. You can read about it in [official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks). In your case this could be something similar to:

```
clenDoc.mustRunAfter clean
incVersion.mustRunAfter clenDoc
asciidoctor.mustRunAfter incVersion
war.mustRunAfter asciidoctor
cleanDocBuild.mustRunAfter war
```